# Iterating through object properties/keys

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, iteration

I'm just starting to learn coding, and i came across this question that i could not understand.

"The second function we'll add will be called search, and it will take a first name as an argument. It will try to match the first name it receives to any of the first names in our friends contact list. If it finds a match, it will log our friend's contact information (firstName, lastName, number, address) to the console."

variables are define as follows :

```
var friends = {}; 
friends.bill = { 
  firstName: "Bill", 
  lastName: "gates", 
  number: "1234567", 
  address: ['bishan','starbucks', 'centertable'] 
}; 

friends.steve = { 
  firstName: "Steve", 
  lastName: "jobs", 
  number: "987654", 
  address: ['orchird', 'ikoma', 'ga'] 
};
```

the answer is as follows :

```
var search = function(name) {
    for(var key in friends) {
        if(friends[key].firstName === name) {
            console.log(friends[key]);
            return friends[key];
        }
    }
};
```

could someone better explain how did the var "key" came about ? and why can't i just input friends.firstName === name, console.log(friends.name), return friends.name ??

would appreciate if someone could explain thank you.

Comment: review official object in mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object

Comment: what does `friends` look like?  what is the output of `console.log(friends[key]);` ?

Comment: var friends = {};

friends.bill = {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "gates",
    number: "1234567",
    address: ['bishan','starbucks', 'centertable']
};

friends.steve = {
    firstName: "Steve",
    lastName: "jobs",
    number: "987654",
    address: ['orchird', 'ikoma', 'ga']
};

Comment: above is how the object friends was presented. (#am reading the moz file) :) ty

Comment: @DarkArtistry Please add this:- `var friends = {}; friends.bill = { firstName: "Bill", lastName: "gates", number: "1234567", address: ['bishan','starbucks', 'centertable'] }; friends.steve = { firstName: "Steve", lastName: "jobs", number: "987654", address: ['orchird', 'ikoma', 'ga'] };` to your question as it is important for the people who would like to answer.

Answer (score 1):

From OP's comment:

```
var friends = {}; 

friends.bill = { 
  firstName: "Bill", 
  lastName: "gates", 
  number: "1234567", 
  address: ['bishan','starbucks', 'centertable'] 
}; 

friends.steve = { 
  firstName: "Steve", 
  lastName: "jobs", 
  number: "987654", 
  address: ['orchird', 'ikoma', 'ga'] 
};
```

`friends` is a nested object which can also be represented like so:

```
friends = {
  bill: { 
      firstName: "Bill", 
      lastName: "gates", 
      number: "1234567", 
      address: ['bishan','starbucks', 'centertable'] 
  },
  steve: { 
      firstName: "Steve", 
      lastName: "jobs", 
      number: "987654", 
      address: ['orchird', 'ikoma', 'ga'] 
  }
}
```

The `for..in` loop iterates over all keys in the `friends` object, with the variable `key` in your case.

> why can't i just input friends.firstName === name, console.log(friends.name), return friends.name ??

Because, to do that, you need to have `firstName` or `name` as a property in `friends`. Since those properties are nested inside (`name` is not event inside the nested objects), there was a `for..in` loop used.

Answer (score 1):

You have an object `friends` that has 2 properties `bill` and `steve` (those are the keys). Calling `friends.bill` will return you an object (the value) with `firstname, lastname, number, address`. You need to iterate all the properties of your object `friends` to find the one you need

You can use [`Object.values(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
var firstNameInput = "Steve";
var friends = {}; 
friends.bill = { 
  firstName: "Bill", 
  lastName: "gates", 
  number: "1234567", 
  address: ['bishan','starbucks', 'centertable'] 
}; 
friends.steve = { 
  firstName: "Steve", 
  lastName: "jobs", 
  number: "987654", 
  address: ['orchird', 'ikoma', 'ga'] 
};

//Iterates all the friends
Object.values(friends).forEach(function(f){
  //Compare the property "firstname" with the input
  if(f.firstName === firstNameInput){
    //Friend found
    console.log(f);
    return;
  }
});
```